# when click a element near input ,will trigger the click event of input

Tags: javascript, html

```
<label  onclick="alert('label')">
    <input type="text"  onclick="alert('input')" >
    <label  onclick="alert('innerLabel-1')">abc</label>
    <label  onclick="alert('innerLabel-2')">cde</label>
</label>
```

when click the 'abc'
and when click the 'cde'

who know the results?
and why it has the differnent results?

Comment: Because that's how labels work... clicking on a `label` triggers the click event handler on the corresponding form element. Since you wrapped all element inside a `label`, the `input` is associated to that `label`. The inner `label`s are useless. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/label

Comment: thank you. but if there are other elements excecpt input.

Comment: in the document ,has a sentence:The HTML Label Element (<label>) represents a caption for an item in a user interface. It can be associated with a control either by using the for attribute, or by placing the control element inside the label element. Such a control is called the labeled control of the label element.

Comment: and what is the  "the control element"

Comment: For example `input` is a control element in that case.